# Get a subset of messages between specific users

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my app, users

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

can send messages

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    from_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    body text NOT NULL CHECK (body <> ''),
    created_at timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0)
);
```

to many recipients

```
CREATE TABLE message_recipients (
    message_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES messages ON DELETE CASCADE,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id, user_id)
);
```

How do I `SELECT` all messages between at least a specific subset of users?

I.e., if there are four users total: {1, 2, 3, 4}, and the subset of users I specify is {1, 2, 3}, then how do I get all messages between users 1, 2, and 3, including all those between users 1, 2, 3, and 4, excluding any messages between only 1 & 2, or 1 & 3, or 2 & 3?

NOTE: I provided [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39797557/242933), but what's a more efficient solution?

Comment: Would you consider specifying the target subset of users in a different way, e.g. by populating a table of `user_id`s used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The query below gets all messages that include a specific subset of users.

```
WITH messages_with_recipients AS (
    SELECT id, from_id, array_agg(r.user_id) AS to_ids, body, created_at
    FROM messages AS m
    JOIN message_recipients AS r
    ON r.message_id = m.id
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 4, 5
)
SELECT id, from_id, to_ids, body, created_at
FROM messages_with_recipients
WHERE array_append(to_ids, from_id) @> '{1, 2, 3}';
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/782657/11) & [PostgreSQL Documentation: Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to create a table or temporary table that holds the specific subset of user IDs (e.g. this could be done within a user defined function). The following query could then be used:

```
WITH messages_not_meeting_requirement AS
(SELECT message_id FROM
 (SELECT m.id AS message_id,
         subq.user_id
  FROM subset s
  CROSS JOIN messages m
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT r.message_id, r.user_id
   FROM messages AS m
   JOIN message_recipients AS r
   ON r.message_id = m.id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.id AS message_id, m.from_id AS userid
   FROM messages AS m) subq
  ON subq.user_id = s.user_id
  AND subq.message_id = m.id) subq2
 WHERE subq2.user_id IS NULL)
SELECT *
FROM messages AS m
WHERE m.id NOT IN (SELECT message_id FROM messages_not_meeting_requirement);
```

See demo here: http://rextester.com/PLQI90029