# Get the latest messages between many users

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many, limit

In my app, users

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

can send messages

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    from_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    body text NOT NULL CHECK (body <> ''),
    created_at timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0)
);
```

to many recipients

```
CREATE TABLE message_recipients (
    message_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES messages ON DELETE CASCADE,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id, user_id)
);
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/782657).

How do I `SELECT` the (e.g., 20) latest messages between a group of users?

E.g., how do I get the 20 latest messages between users 1, 2, and 3? I.e., how do I get the messages limited to the latest 20 that 1 has sent to both 2 & 3, 2 has sent to both 1 & 3, and 3 has sent to both 1 & 2?

NOTE: I don't want to assign the messages to channels. I want to filter them by senders & receivers.

Related Question: [Get a subset of messages between specific users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797556/get-a-subset-of-messages-between-specific-users)

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate the participants for each message, then you can match the participant list.

```
WITH target_group (members) AS (
  VALUES (ARRAY [1, 2, 3] :: BIGINT [])
), message_group AS (
    SELECT
      -- message id
      m.id,
      -- aggregate the ids of all message parties
      array_agg(mr.user_id) || m.from_id AS members
    FROM message_recipients mr
      JOIN messages m ON m.id = mr.message_id
      JOIN target_group tg ON tg.members @> ARRAY [m.from_id]
    GROUP BY m.id
)
SELECT
  m.id,
  m.body
FROM message_group mg
  JOIN messages m ON m.id = mg.id
  JOIN target_group tg ON tg.members @> mg.members AND array_length(tg.members, 1) = array_length(mg.members, 1)
ORDER BY m.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```